# Can the “/dev/random” device be edited to make the RNG predictable on my computer?

Tags: linux, random-number-generator

Is it possible, with super user access, to edit my `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` in such a way that even OS-generated random numbers are predictable?

I am trying to understand if I sent an executable (e.g. a game) to someone that relies on system RNG, could they manipulate their own `/dev/random` to hack my program so that they can predict the program’s random output?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a classic “[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)” so will ask: What is your overall goal here?

Comment: Understanding if I sent an executable (e.g. a game) to someone that relies on system RNG, could they manipulate their own /dev/random to hack my program so it they can predict the program's random output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` work is that they call kernel code to calculate the next bytes.

You can replace this code with your own code, recompile the kernel, reboot, and have a predictable sequence. With superuser access, you could also live-patch the existing kernel to the same effect (provided you have a good idea which kernel is used on the system).

So yes, it's possible to do that, but it takes quite some effort.

> Understanding if I sent an executable (e.g. a game) to someone that relies on system RNG, could they manipulate their own /dev/random to hack my program so it they can predict the program's random output?

Yes, they could. Now the XY question is what you want to do with your program, so that this other person can take advantage of it.

In general, keep in mind that the other person can reverse engineer the assembly code of your program, and make any changes they want. Instead of fiddling with the kernel, it would be much simpler to just look at the places in your program where you read from `/dev/random`, and change those reads to always return zero (or something similar).

So whatever scheme you have in mind to keep secrets from the other person: It's likely not going to work. But we don't know, unless you tell us the X ("what do you want to achieve?") to your Y.

Comment: Clear. Thank you.